# My VPS Server's TimeZone always resets on reboot - Why?

Tags: windows-server-2003, vps, timezone, virtuozzo

I'm using a VPS running Virtuozzo Containers with Parallels. Every time I reboot it sets the server's TimeZone to GMT+01 Amsterdam. If I change that to GMT+00 London and then reboot, it gets set back to Amsterdam again. Is there any way I can prevent this?

I'm also have a very strange issue whereby .Net is reporting that the DateTime.Now as the +01 Amsterdam time instead of +00 GMT, even after I've change it to London's TimeZone.

Is there somewhere else I need to change the TimeZone apart from in the Timezone tab under the system clock?

Answer (score 1):

What version of Virtuozzo are you running?  This looks a lot like a bug in Virtuozzo version 3.5.1 that was completely fixed in versions 4 and beyond.

Answer (score -1):

After having it be pointed-out that I missed the "Windows" reference, it sounds like the underlying virtualization layer is holding time permanently - perhaps, as has been mentioned elsewhere, as a bug in the edition of Virtuozzo.

This is probably an issue you need to take up with your VPS provider.

*original answer below*
Might check [hwclock](http://linux.die.net/man/8/hwclock), but it sounds like the VPS's settings require it to go back to the underlying host's timezone setting.

Comment: Pointing at a linux manpage for a Win2k3 server?

Comment: honestly - missed the tag for "windows-server-2003": nothing in the question indicated platform :)